# Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld"

Tags: spring, maven-2, jstl

there's this issue with JSTL I'm stuck with for the past couple of days. Any help is appreciated.

Tomcat 6.0.28
Eclipse: Helios

pom.xml :

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>   
  <groupId>taglibs</groupId> 
  <artifactId>standard</artifactId> 
  <version>1.1.2</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>   
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> 
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page session="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="utilfn" uri="/utility-functions" %>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

When I deploy the Maven-built war on tomcat 6 using the manager it works fine. 
When I run it as "Run As > Run On Server" inside eclipse, I get this:

> Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/<- location ->/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Myproject/WEB-INF/lib/standard-1.1.2.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV

Wherever I look, it says the same thing:

> 1. Make sure servlet-api and jsp-api are not in lib
> 2. Make sure to use the right JSTL version and URI that goes with JSP 2.0.

And they seem to be fine as I can deploy the war independently. So what's wrong here!?

Comment: Well written question, plenty of examples. Good job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that 
`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Myproject/WEB-INF/lib/standard-1.1.2.jar` is not corrupted (and do some cleanup if required).

Comment: Even though standard-1.1.2.jar was not the issue, I'm still accepting your answer, because I failed to check that location. It just didn't occur to me. 
The issue was that servlet-api.jar was copied over to that location somehow when I deleted and reconfigured my server inside Eclipse. Deleting that file solved the issue. 

Every time I choose "Clean" and "Clean Tomcat Work Directory" from the server context menu, the jar appears back there though. I'm not sure why/how. But as of now, deleting that file manually is making it work.
Thank you for the response!

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. I still haven't figured out why/how the jar reappears though - have you?

Comment: It happened to me too that sometimes JAR are included even if marked as provided in pom, I've found a solution with packagingExcludes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477504/maven-javax-servlet-specification-deployed

Answer (score 16):

After i moved using Indigo Eclipse 3.7 and took the lasted update of m2e, this problem happened to me, i remove the dependency below it worked well.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure why the issues was gone, as my understanding new version of m2e has jsp compilation library already.

Answer (score 6):

remove :

     javax.servlet.jsp 
   jsp-api 
   2.0
   provided

from you pom.xml and that should do.. it worked in my case :-)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is an issue with maven/m2eclipse plugin. Even I am seeing the same issue. By default it is pushing all the jar files to server lib directory. Which includes the scope "provided" jar files. This issue was fixed in old versions of m2eclipse. But it got introduced again it seems.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, m2e 1.0 is including the provided JARs, as you say. That's a problem because Tomcat doesn't want javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api as Sobree notes above.

Answer (score 2):

**Quickfix:**

Make a backup of .classpath and .project and .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component.

Run this command:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Or, **right-click** over the project, in the **Maven** sub-menu, you have an **Update Project...** command which I think does the same thing.

Republish.

**Explanation:**

You likely added all Maven Dependencies as a Deployment Assembly to your project.  This copies all Maven class path entries to the WEB-INF/lib directory.  Open your .classpath file (at the root of your project) and you'll probably find the following XML:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

That means copy EVERY .jar file which becomes a problem in this case.

Updating the project should remove the XML block above and explicitly list the JAR files.

So, if you re-open .classpath, you'll see this instead:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.1/gson-2.2.1.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.1/gson-2.2.1-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1-sources.jar"/>
...
```

This is for the classpath which you still need, but it removed the dependency to copy them to lib.  Instead, if you open .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component/, you'll see that the JAR files are now explicitly listed:

```
<dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/classpath/var/M2_REPO/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.1/gson-2.2.1.jar">
  <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
```

And, you'll note that jsp-api-2.1.jar is now missing.  Apply the same logic to the other JAR files.

Does anyone know how to make this automatic?

Answer (score 0):

platform: eclipse 3.7 indigo, tomcat 6.0.29
commented out the following dependencies in pom.xml:

```
javax.servlet  
org.apache.taglibs
```

this cleared up the issue (as they are provided via tomcat) ...

Comment: The questioner had accepted a completely different solution months before your answer, so this was not his problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jay's answer.  I have same issue here.  If I remove jsp-api from pom.xlm, maven test will fail because it cannot find jspWriter class in jsp-api jar.  If I keep jsp-api in pom and set it to 'provided' or 'test', tomcat side will fail as the m2e plugin pushes jsp-api jar to maven dependencies which is then included in my tomcat deployed lib.  I would say it's plugin issue as jsp-api has to be declared in pom.xml as provided because it is provided by application servers.
I can't find any way of solving this issue but to manually delete the jsp-api every time after tomcat server synch.

Answer (score 0):

With Eclipse, please assure that you installed 'Maven Integration for Eclipse **WTP** '
With the other plugin without WTP, eclipse change your classpath and include servlet-api.jar in your webapps.

Comment: While your answer may be helpful, it has already been solved by doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

You must exclude jsp-api dependency from jstl import in your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed jsp-api 2.0 from 
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Myproject/WEB-INF/lib/
this worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in netbeans IDE 8.0.2. It turns out my part was set to 8080 for outgoing and shutdown. I changed the outgoing to 8081 for Tomcat server. It worked! I then changed my shutdown port 8005. To change go to Tools>Servers>

My tomcat server now works.