# Maven: javax.servlet specification deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

I've a web application configured with Maven which uses a library, also configured with Maven and when I package geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar is included in WEB-INF/lib and I don't understand why.

I check the library with mvn dependency:tree

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep geronimo
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:provided
```

I check my web app:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep geronimo
$
```

However when I run mvn:package the file gets included in WEB-INF/lib.

When I run mvn tomcat:run I can see:

INFO: validateJarFile(/home/stivlo/workspace/private/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Why and how to avoid? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**: as requested I add the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.obliquid</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>private webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- For Jakarta ORO -->
        <repository>
            <id>mvnsearch</id>
            <name>Maven Search</name>
            <url>http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.obliquid.helpers</groupId>
            <artifactId>obliquid-helpers</artifactId>
            <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>private</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UPDATE 2**: I followed the advice of Stephen C and modified the build section as follows:

```
<build>
    <finalName>private</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.obliquid</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test-webapp</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However geronimo*.jar still gets included. I guess I've made a mistake in this configuration.

**UPDATE 3**: Stephen C. says that I should use

> the groupId the artifactId of the WAR
>   file that contains the JAR file(s)
>   that you are trying to exclude.

I didn't know that WAR files could have a groupId and artifactId, in fact in my pom.xml I don't see any. My project builds a WAR file and has a groupId and an artifactId and those were the ones I tested above without success.

The dependency causing the problem is the following (is a JAR, not a WAR):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.obliquid.helpers</groupId>
    <artifactId>obliquid-helpers</artifactId>
    <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I try to use the groupId and artifactId listed in this dependency I've the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war
>   (default-war) on project test-webapp:
>   overlay [ id
>   org.obliquid.helpers:obliquid-helpers]
>   is not a dependency of the project. ->
>   [Help 1]

If I try to use the groupId and artifactId of the JAR included by org.obliquid.helpers:

```
<groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
<artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>)
```

I have the same error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war
>   (default-war) on project test-webapp:
>   overlay [ id
>   org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec]
>   is not a dependency of the project. ->
>   [Help 1]

Reading the War plugin documentation, I found a section about [creating skinny WARs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html). So I tried the following:

```
<build>
    <finalName>private</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Still without any success, geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar is still there!

```
<groupId>org.obliquid.helpers</groupId>
<artifactId>obliquid-helpers</artifactId>
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project test-webapp: overlay [ id org.obliquid.helpers:obliquid-helpers] is not a dependency of the project. -> [Help 1]

```
<groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
<artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project test-webapp: overlay [ id org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec] is not a dependency of the project. -> [Help 1]

**UPDATE 4**: I discovered that the target/private.war file is not a zip of target/private/ directory, but the exclusions are done at packaging time and not by deleting files in target/private/ -- This means, I've to re-test all the things I did before.

- Suggestion of gouki: doesn't work, the JAR is still there also in the WAR file.
- Suggestion of Stephen C., maybe mis-understood: actually I just noticed that the pom.xml is always invalid whatever groupId/artifactId I put of the three possibilities explained above. So they didn't work for me.
- What I found in the documentation (packagingExcludes), works.

Now, if I had to choose one of he answers I would choose Stephen C., because he helped me pointing at the documentation of the WAR plugin (I was reading in the wrong places). However I'd accept an answer that doesn't work, at least in the way I tried (probably wrong). So I'm not going to accept any answer, and add a new answer myself with the final working configuration.

**UPDATE 5**: I post the relevant part of the pom.xml of obliquid-helpers, that mentions geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec. I've marked it optional and with scope provided, still it gets included by a web-app, unless I mark it as "packagingExclude" in the maven-war-plugin configuration.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.obliquid.helpers</groupId>
  <artifactId>obliquid-helpers</artifactId>
  <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>obliquid-helpers</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    [...]
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    [...]

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Sure, I am adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thank gouki and Stephen C. for helping me. However their proposed solution didn't work for me. I'm grateful to them, but I can't accept their answer, because it would be misleading since it didn't work for this problem. I've upvoted Stephen C. answer, because he pointed me to the right documentation, which was essential to solve the problem.

Reading the WAR plugin documentation, especially the war:war mojo section, I've found an example on how to create Skinny WARs, which did the trick. So here is below the working configuration, to be added to the build section:

```
<build>
    <finalName>private</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar</packagingExcludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The archive part is probably not really needed, but I will find out when I deploy the WAR. The part that does the trick is the packagingExcludes tag, that can contain a *comma separated list of tokens to exclude from the WAR before packaging*.

Comment: I'd like to point out that my advice was predicated on the assumption that you were using WAR file overlays ... which you aren't doing.

Comment: I also think that you haven't go to the bottom of this.  Why was that JAR file a dependency in the first place?  Is / was it mentioned in **any** for your POM files?  Is it mentioned in any of the POM files of your POM's dependants?  Are you using some funky plugin that is adding a dependent behind your back?  Dependants don't get pulled in without there being some mention somewhere ...

Comment: I see, in the question I mention that I use "a library also configured with Maven", maybe I should have told also that was packaged as JAR...  About the second comment: you're right, I still don't know why it was included in the first place. I post the pom.xml of obliquid-helpers

Comment: I've posted UPDATE 5 with the pom.xml of obliquid-helpers which is included by the web-app

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, something has a dependency on that JAR file.  If it is not showing up in the dependency tree, perhaps it is due to a dependency of your webapp WAR file on another WAR file that has this dependency.

If that is the case, then you could get add an `<excludes>` to the `<overlay>` element of the build descriptor for the WAR file plugin; e.g.

```
...
<build>
  <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <overlays>
            <overlay>
              <groupId>xxx</groupId>
              <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/whatever.jar</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </overlay>
          </overlays>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
```

---

If you are using WAR file overlays, you should always include the `clean` target in the build.  Otherwise you can get old dependencies hanging around in the WAR file.  (IIRC, there is a Warning in the Maven output each time you build an overlaid WAR without cleaning!)

In fact, this could be the root cause of your problems.  For instance, if previously you had the "geronimo" as an ordinary dependency and you haven't run `mvn clean` since then, the JAR file could still be hanging around.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the exclude as you suggested, but geronimo*.jar is still included. I guess I made some mistake.. When you say: <groupId>xxx</groupId> <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>, does it mean of my webapp? I put the ones of my webapp.

Comment: No.  I mean the groupId the artifactId of the WAR file that contains the JAR file(s) that you are trying to exclude.  Read the Maven WAR file plugin documentation!!

Comment: Ok, I read already a lot about Maven, but not enough, on your suggestion I went here to read more http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html -- I tried three different things and they all failed - here I can't format the text properly, I am going to update the question.

Comment: Oops, update: the skinny war seems to work. All JARs are there in target/private/ directory, but are not added to target/private.war directory. I didn't know they could be different. I lack experience with Maven. I will re-try all configurations and amend my UPDATE 3.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your pom.xml, the only dependency that might have dependency on geronimo servlet is

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.obliquid.helpers</groupId>
        <artifactId>obliquid-helpers</artifactId>
        <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can you try excluding the geronimo in this dependency?

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.obliquid.helpers</groupId>
            <artifactId>obliquid-helpers</artifactId>
            <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, it's that one, the strange thing is that is marked as "provided", which afaik would mean that should not be included in packaging. Now I try your solution and let you know, thanks.

Comment: I don't know why, but even adding the exclusion inside the dependency, geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar is still there :-(

Comment: You might be able to use `<dependencyManagement>` to make it be “provided” anyway.

Comment: try: mvn clean package -DskipTests  ; try cleaning the target directory to make sure that there ain't no geronimo jar in it from previous build.

Comment: Search your target directory if there is a geronimo jar in it. If there is, do a 'mvn clean' then run 'mvn package'

Comment: I've always run mvn clean before any mvn package to be sure.