# Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I create a Spring MVC project from Spring template using the STS plugin. However when I run the application there's an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp(1,63) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/H:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/imgateway/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
```

Anyone have experienced this kind of issue?

Comment: I have tried using Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7 for the runtime, however I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing with the same situation and I realize that the error is thrown, *obviously*, because something went wrong with JSTL. Since, STS templates rely on Maven2, you should need to manually **delete the JSTL artifact from your local Maven2 repository**.

**In Windows 7:**
Delete the folder `c:\Users\<Username>\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\`.

**In Linux:** Delete the folder `/home/<Username>/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/`

**Note:** This is not the fault of STS, it just happens when an artifact was corrupted while being downloaded from the Internet. Deleting the arfifact will *force* Maven2 to re-download it. Finally, it could happen with any artifact/file downloaded from the web.

Answer (score 12):

Asked a several times before on StackOverflow:
[Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452403/unable-to-read-tld-meta-inf-c-tld)

I did blog a potential answer to this once: http://blog.flurdy.com/2010/07/jetty-tomcat-jsp.html

Depending on if your project uses maven you will need to ensure jsp-api is not included but provided by Tomcat instead by eg:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

do NOT package javax.servlet.jsp.jar with your webapp, it confuses tomcat :P

We were getting the exact same error, removing javax.servlet.jsp.jar from the WEB-INF/lib sorted it

Answer (score 1):

With Eclipse, please assure that you installed 'Maven Integration for Eclipse **WTP** '
With the other plugin without WTP, eclipse change your classpath and include servlet-api.jar in your webapps.

Answer (score 0):

The same default come with me today. This is a mistake caused by *`servlet-api.jar`* and 
*`jsp-api.jar`*,and you may need this two in you develop code,so ensure them appear in your pom.xml with provided. It looks work fine with me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```