# Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class | Tomcat 7, Eclipse STS

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat7

I am trying to Migrate a web application from Webspiere to Tomcat 7. I am using Spring Tool Suit (sts). I get the following exception when I try to run the applcation. The project is not maintained as a maven project. I tried both options having jsp jar and servlet jar from class path and not having them. Still the issue is the same.

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /myapp threw load() exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /admin_login.jsp (line: 3, column: 0) Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are missing the JSTL tag library in the classpath or you might have missed the standard.jar in your classpath.

Check [this](http://www.techcrony.info/2009/03/24/nitingautam/orgapachejasperjasperexception-failed-to-load-or-instantiate-taglibraryvalidator-class-orgapachetaglibsstandardtlvjstlcoretlv/)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452403/unable-to-read-tld-meta-inf-c-tld) .

Comment: Thanks Lakshmi.It solved the problem,now I have different issue.. |SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport| I will look into it.if u have an idea about it,help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: @TharinduVishwanath Glad you figured it you are welcome Check your Jstl jar for the above class may be your jar does not contain the required class file use the latest version of jstl jar..may be jstl-1.2.jar